# Using a different template / application view for one specific view

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

The main structure of my app is defined in `application.hbs` template. I want to use this structure for all views in the application except for one: the login page (`/login`). I can not figure out how to go about that. Any insights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's surprisingly easy if you know the pieces.

I've made a simple ember-cli app to demo it, here is the relevant commit: https://github.com/zeppelin/ember-dynamic-app-template/commit/9a07be34413bc6208485c7405f375317fecb0b5f